# Positionning numbers at vertices of a cube with arithmetical constraints

Tags: geometry, real-numbers

Is it possible to position a number at each vertex of a cube taken from the set `1,2,...,9` so that the sum of vertex numbers of each face are the same and not divisible by the number not taken into numbering.

I try to solve this but I have problems. Thanks for help.

Comment: What is the source of this problem, please?

Comment: My problem is: How to prove that exist only one solution?

Comment: And my question is, where did you find this question?

Comment: On the Internet (on Polish website)

Comment: Good. And what did it say there, about where the problem came from?

Comment: Every number is divisible by 1, so either I don’t understand the question correctly or it is ill posed.

Comment: @Prudi you leave out one of the nine numbers, and then you want the sum of the vertex numbers of each face to not be divisible by the one number you've left out. So by your observation you can't choose to leave out the number $1$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson thanks, that makes sense. I didn’t read correctly and thought we were in a symmetric situation, where all numbers are present at the cube. Big brain time.

Answer (score 1):

If the number $x$ is left out, then the remaining numbers sum to $45-x$. This should be an even number (so $x$ must be odd) because opposite faces have the same sum, and $(45-x)/2$ should not be divisible by $x$. This leaves us $x=7$ and that the faces should sum to $19$.

Next, if all faces should have the same sum, then opposite edges should have equal sums because adjacent faces share edges. From this observation, it follows that $1, 9$ must be on a single edge.

Put $1, 9$ on some edge $e$ from faces $f_1, f_2$. The other edges of $f_1, f_2$ must add to $9$ and there's only two ways this can happen - $3+6$ or $4+5$ (because $1, 7$ are removed).

Moreover, you can't have $1, 3$ on the same edge because the opposite edge must then add to $4$ which is not possible from the remaining numbers - $2, 4, 5, 8$.

Therefore, one of the faces, say the top face, must have numbers:
$$\begin{matrix}
1&&9\\
&&&&\\
6&&3
\end{matrix}$$

From here you can fill the rest of the cube using the fact that opposite edges should have the same sum and that gives you exactly one solution:
$1, 9, 3, 6$ on the top face anticlockwise as above and $4, 5, 2, 8$ on the bottom face anticlocwise with 4 below 1.

I haven't figured out how to draw a cube in my answer, so hope this makes sense:

$$\begin{matrix}
&1&&9\\
6&&3&\\
&4&&5\\
8&&2&
\end{matrix}$$